# `npm init react-app` leads to `'React' is not defined no-undef` when changing function component to class component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I used `npm init react-app appname` which creates, among other files, `App.js`. In that file is a function component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <SomeJSX />
  );
}
```

I edited the function component into a class component, like so:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <TheSameJSX />
    );
  }
}
```

Now, when I run `npm start`, I get an error:

```
Failed to compile

src/App.js
  Line 4:19:  'React' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I imagine I need to add some setting somewhere that will automatically include React without me needing to explicitly `import` it at the top of every file. How do I do this? And why does this npm package not do that by default? I know a bit about javascript (and html and css), and have read a bit about React, but I am completely unaware of how npm or webpack works.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: To clarify, I know how to import stuff with javascript. I can easily add `import React from 'react';` to the file and make it work. However, I find it difficult to believe that adding an `import` statement to every single javascript file is the recommended method, and I don't understand why this example app wouldn't be set up so as to avoid having to do that. Am I mistaken? Do I really need to manually import the same thing over and over again within the same project? Could I set a global variable to `React` so that I can use it from wherever?

Answer (score 0):

In your default function component you're not extending any classes and just writing a simple function

```
function App() {
      return (
        <SomeJSX />
      );
    }
```

In class component, you're in fact extending the Class `Component` by `React.Component` provided by React default export object and hence you must import it from the package

```
//only use one of these 
import * as React from "react"; 
import {Component} from "react"; // you can directly extend without writing `React.` with this import 
import React from "react"
```

So your code would be

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <TheSameJSX />
    );
  }
}
```

Any of the above imports should be fine with a preference to the first and second one.